# Show a function is continuous along any line

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider the function $ f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$ f(x,y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{for $x^2<y<3x^2$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$

Now this function is obviously not continuous at the origin as if I can approach it along $(t,2t)$ with arbitrarily small values of $t$ and find that the limit disagrees with $f(0,0)$ .

How can I prove that this function is continuous along any line?

or in other words prove that $g(t) = f(\alpha + at,\beta + bt)$ is continuous for any $\alpha,\beta,a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

I am stuck because of the way the function is defined. I tried considering cases when $\alpha > \beta, \beta > \alpha$ etc. but that seems to get me nowhere. Any suggestion as to how I can approach this ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.  Try the vertical line through $(1,1)$.

Comment: What you should be trying to do is to show the function is continuous *at the origin* when you restrict to any line through the origin. Somewhere the truth got buried in a translation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, I think I can show that, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $g(t)=f(t,t)$ and look at the point $(1/3,1/3)$, the point is on the curve $y=3x^{2}$ and if $t\rightarrow 1/3^{-}$, then $f(t,t)\rightarrow 0$ and if $t\rightarrow 1/3^{+}$, then $f(t,t)\rightarrow 1$, $g$ is not continuous at $t=1/3$.